# If-Else when renaming files in a directory

Tags: python, if-statement, directory, conditional-statements, rename

I am developing a script to rename files within a given directory.
With the iterative nature of programming, I wish to utilize an "if-else" approach to ensure files that were already labeled correctly can be ignored.

```
files_location = os.listdir(path)
new_entry_name = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'plum', 'strawberry']

i = 0
for entry in files_location:
    if entry == new_entry_name[i]:
        i = i+1
    if entry != new_entry_name[i]:
        os.rename(os.path.join(path,entry), os.path.join(path,new_entry_name[i]))
        i = i+1
    else:
        print('Run complete')
```

However, I receive the following error which seems to indicate my if-else conditional statements are not letting my bypass entries that were renamed already.
As we see below, a previously renamed file 'cherry' seems to be blocking further renaming:

```
[WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:/Users/...\\cherry' -> 'C:/Users/...\\apple'
```

Comment: You are attempting to rename a file into another existing file. Consider printing all `os.path.join(path,new_entry_name[i])` and check if any of them indeed exists.

Comment: Hi DyZ, it sounds like I need to incorporate a check in my script to bypass files that have already been renamed. Do you have any suggestions in how I may do this?

Comment: Check `if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,new_entry_name[i]))` before renaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so here is my breakdown of a solution. Perhaps not the best solution, but I've tried to stay true to your code as well as I could. There are a number of different considerations in order to effectively deliver your code.

1) As I mentioned in my comment, the list presents a finite amount of options for names and also limits your ability to iterate by constraining the iteration to the length of the list. Otherwise, you end up with an index error when you run out of items in the list. This error would occur when the number of folders in the target directory is greater than the number of items in your list.

2) There needs to be some dynamic way of assigning a unique value to different folder names. Most of the time, if you're worried about having the same file name, or know it will be the same, you attach something you know will be unique. In this case a date/time stamp. As you can see. the first folders will match the list item names then, when we restart at apple again, it will tap into our condition statement to ensure it's not in the directory and will attach our unique addition of a date/time stamp.

3) Checking for the presence of folders or files with the same name is done with os.path.exists this is just another way of seeing whether a path exists and will return a Boolean value. It's a useful tool that comes up in file operations.

To follow the logic of this code, I would create a directory, set up five new folders. Run this script. You'll see all the unique names in the directory. Now add two new folders to the directory and run the script again. You should get apple(date/time) and orange(date/time) and all the other originals still there.

```
import os
import datetime
from time import sleep

path = 'your target directory'


files_location = os.listdir(path)
new_entry_name = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'plum', 'strawberry']

i = 0

for folder in files_location:  # STARTS ITERATING THROUGH FOLDERS IN TARGET DIRECTORY
    sleep(3)
    print('ON THIS FOLDER: ' + folder)
    if folder in new_entry_name:  # IF THE FOLDER NAME IS IN LIST, THEN PASS
        print('Folder: ' + folder + ' is in list')
        pass

    else:
        print(folder + ' is not in the list')
        print('Checking if proposed folder name ' + new_entry_name[i] + ' is in directory')

        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(path, new_entry_name[i])):  # CHECKS NEW FOLDER NAME BEFORE RENAMING
            print('Proposed name is taken, creating alternate')
            currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()
            new_name = new_entry_name[i] + currentDT.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')  # ATTACHES DATETIME TO LIST ITEM
            print('Renaming with alternate name')
            os.rename(os.path.join(path, folder), os.path.join(path, new_name))  # RENAMES WITH DATETIME
            if i == 4:  # AVOIDS LIST INDEX ERROR BY CYCLING i BACK TO APPLE WHEN THE LIST WOULD BE EXHAUSTED
                i -= 4
            else:
                i += 1

        else:
            # RENAMES FOLDER IF IT DOESN'T EXIST IN DIRECTORY
            print('Renaming folder')
            os.rename(os.path.join(path, folder), os.path.join(path, new_entry_name[i]))
            if i == 4:
                i -= 4
            else:
                i += 1
```

Let me know if the code doesn't run. Also, feel free to ask if you need me to clarify something or help get you going in the right direction.

Comment: cjonesrun, you made the purpose of each step and how they communicate with each other very clear. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Anytime! Good luck in your pursuits!

Answer (score 0):

To make the problem clearer set up the following:

Make a directory with five new folders - Folder(1), Folder(2), etc.

Also, change your else statement to 'pass.' Your script will run as intended labeling each of the folders a unique fruit name. The issue will come when you run the script the second time. You'll get the error that you've been seeing, but the reason why will be more obvious. Your logic only compares the file name against i +1. NOT against all possible items in the list. So, during the iteration, you script will attempt to name the file the same as one that already exists, thus getting the windows error. The error is basically saying I won't name this the same thing. To see this slowed down (while you could use a debugger) I've set up your script slightly modified to let you see what logical conditions are being met and when. To use this script, delete all the folders in that directory and create new generic empty ones Folder1, Folder2, etc. Run my script and it will work the first time as before. Fun it a second time, and you'll see the error more plainly.

```
import os
from time import sleep
path = 'path to target directory containing blank files'


files_location = os.listdir(path)
new_entry_name = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'plum', 'strawberry']


i = 0
for folder in files_location:
    print('STARTING LOOP')
    sleep(5)
    print('USING THIS FOLDER: ' + folder)
    print('i IS CURRENTLY SET AT ' + str(i))

    if folder == new_entry_name[i]:
        print('THIS FOLDER MET THE FIRST CONDITIONAL STATEMENT')
        print(new_entry_name[i])
        i += 1

    elif folder != new_entry_name[i]:
        print('FOLDER ' + folder + ' SHOULD BE RENAMED BECAUSE IT DOES NOT MATCH new_entry_name_item' + str(i))
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, folder), os.path.join(path, new_entry_name[i]))
        i += 1
        print('FOLDER RENAMED')
        sleep(10)
    else:
        print('RUN COMPLETE')
```

To fix this, I would recommend doing what DyZ suggested and either checking the name against all entries in the directory or all entries in your list.

Comment: cjonesrun, thank you for providing this breakdown. You're exactly right, it is always the second run when I receive this error.
How would you suggest performing such a check in my script to allow me to "skip" folders that have been renamed already?

Comment: Anytime! Yes, I was going to take a crack at that tonight and write something up. My thought is that, since the list is finite in length, obviously you always run into the issue of exhausting names. However, I'll write up a small snip of code that I would approach this problem with. I won't say it will be the best answer as there are a ton of talented coders, but it may steer you in the right direction. I'll post again later.